# ubuntu 20.04 hanging while working

Tags: kernel, 20.04, freeze

have installed ubuntu 20.04 for about two(2) week now and they was no issue. but recently noticed the system keeps hanging for no reason while using. please is there any fix to this? This is very disturbing

free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       2.3Gi       3.1Gi       452Mi       2.3Gi       4.7Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

vm.swappiness = 60

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
ls: cannot access '/home/hola/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23 08:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May 23 15:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 23 08:35 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 08:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 08:35 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: How much swap space do you have? `free -h` Read `man mkswap;man swapon` and create some swap space - it looks like RAM exhaustion.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: actually i feel its chrome that is causing the problem... never experienced freezing since i uninstalled it @heynnema

Comment: Chrome may just be a symptom, not really the cause. If you show me the info I requested, we might get a different perspective on your problem.

Comment: @heynnema edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the info. Everything looks normal. What apps do you normally run? When it hangs, does it eventually recover? When you had Chrome, how many open tabs did you normally have?

Comment: @heynnema i make use of just vsCode or atom and a browser(i use firefox before but when i switched to chrome the freezing started

Comment: Everything looks normal. Do you have any Chrome extensions/apps/add-ons installed? You could run a memory test... just to eliminate that... Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of freezes and hangs and it seems to be fixed now. I am a KDE user and installed kde-full. It looks like some required libraries might have changed from 19.10 to 20.04 and that installed the missing libraries and packages. It's been working perfectly sine I did this.

Comment: So what's the fix exactly, please? I seem not to get it clearly.

Comment: @shadwMan how did you fixed the missing library